# jax-rs vs HttpServlet in jee

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jax-ws

which one is better for implementing **restful** architecture?

jax-rs example :

```
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return xmlHello();
  }
```

servlet example :

```
    protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException , IOException
    {
        //showUsers( response);
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

**I can't DELETE THIS QUESTION... Please do not give me a negative rating... thanks.**

And so, I prefer to use **servlet** for implementing the restful... Because of making easy and flexible designs...

Answer (score 1):

This decision is entirely up to you and is primarily matter of preference.

However, Jax-RS will provide utilities (via annotations) which lead to cleaner code when developing RESTful applications.